# How to Format a Value within a JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I'm working on a J2EE application which uses Struts (v1) and I would like to format a value being displayed in a JSP. The value to be displayed is a 7 or 8 digit integer and I would like to insert dashes into it, like so:

```
1234567 -> 1-234-567
12345678 -> 12-345-678
```

What is the best way to go about this? My first thought was to write a special getter in my form bean which would return the specially formatted String, rather than the Integer. That, of course, seems very smelly - I don't want to add methods to my beans just to format things in my JSP.

Another option I considered was to use bean:write's format attribute. Unfortunately, I can find lots of documentation on how to use format when you're trying to format a date, but I just can't seem to find the correct syntax for working with arbitrary values.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some researching on `fmt:formatNumber`... I think using `-` is causing some weird problem because `,` is the only safe grouping separator. Based on the documentation, it seems like you can comment special character using single quotes, but I don't think it applies in your case.

So, here's my workaround:-

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<c:set var="foo" value="12345678"/>
<fmt:formatNumber value="${foo}" pattern="00,00,000" var="result"/>
${fn:replace(result, ",", "-")}
```

This works for me. Basically, I use commas instead of dashes, then use the replace function to convert it back to dashes... not quite an elegant solution.

Comment: I tried doing something very similar with the bean:write tag, like this: <bean:write name="x" property="foo" format="00-000-000" /> and I get the same result doing this as I get when trying to execute your code above. I get the number, with two dashes afterwards, like this: 1234567--. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I display this formatted number in multiple locations and I didn't like having to place these three lines in my JSP every time I needed to display it. As such, I opted to put a method into my form bean that would format the value and send it back as a String. Not perfect, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

With bean:write, you can only use DateFormat and DecimalFormat, which can't do what you're looking to do here (DecimalFormat doesn't do totally free form formatting and reserves the - as a special character).

The Struts docs recommend just formatting it in your ActionForm: http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/faq.html#tags

If you really, really want to do it in your JSP, you'll probably have to write your own tag library to handle it. Not even the JSTL can really even handle this for you: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Use NumberFormat to format numbers.

API : http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Example:

http://www.kodejava.org/examples/102.html

Comment: This answer is not very useful in JSP context. The general consensus is that putting raw Java code in JSP files is a poor practice.

Comment: Java code need not be in JSP. It could be used to define a TAG in JSP that formats numbers as per this format. Or a TAG that accepts both Number and NumberFormat

Answer (score -1):

use something along these lines, it should help you out!!:

```
<bean:write name="formBean" property="dashedNum" format="###'-'###'-'###"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Please test code before submitting it as an answer.